# Need assistance a script that counts until two numbers are divisible

Tags: python

This is for a school assignment and I'm incredibly new to programming in general, the purpose of the code is to create a little dialog as if the user were speaking with Count Von Count. In this section of the assignment we have to take the users favorite number and a chosen number and if they aren't divisible by each other than we count by the users favorite number to the next highest number from the chosen number that is divisible. Sorry if I explained it in some strange way that no one really understands, I'm not the best with explaining.

```
  count = 0
favorite_number = input("What is your favorite number")
chosen_number = input("Choose a number")
divisibility = int(chosen_number) % int(favorite_number)
if int(chosen_number) % int(favorite_number) != 0:
    while int(divisibility) != 0:
        int(chosen_number) + 1
        if int(divisibility) == 0:
            print(f"The Count: {chosen_number} isn't divisble by {favorite_number} so lets try counting to {divisibility} instead! I will be counting by {favorite_number} to {divisibility}")
            while (count) < int(divisibility):
                print((count)-2)
                (count) += int(favorite_number)
                if (count) < int(divisibility):
                    print(f"The Count: And thats how you count to {divisibility}!")
```

Comment: One thing that would help in readability, would be to put `int()` around your inputs then you don't have to use it everywhere after. so `chosen_number = int(input("Choose a number"))` then you don't have to use `int(chosen_number)` after that.

Comment: Also, what are you getting as output and what do you think the output should be for given inputs?